# Read excel using apache poi - Hashmap,ArrayList

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to read column values using column headers in excel (using java). As attached in the image, suppose i want to read for header "city", all subsequent cells under the column and display them . How will i do that ?

Looking at examples over the internet, i found most of the examples iterating using an iterator  over the row.

Suppose i have a hashmap of key as headers of excel and subsequent values stored in ArrayList. Something like

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashmap = 
                new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

How should i proceed ? Can anyone help me with the code and logic?

Please do not mark this as duplicate, i have tried searching over stackoverflow and internet, but most of them iterate using the row.

Comment: Not clear where the problem is here. Just iterate over the rows and [getCell(4)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int)), which is column `E` from each row.

Comment: I want to make it generic. Not a specific row or column. For a particular column header, i want to extract all cell values.  If you can help me with some piece of code for the same, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly read all the cells in a column without iterating over the rows as that is the way data is stored in an excel sheet (in rows, not in columns). A workaround could be to transpose the rows and columns like it is shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12366/), and then iterating over the rows to get your data in the `Hashmap` as you indicated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Rather than transposing rows and columns , is there a way, we can retrieve all cells based on the column header name ?

Comment: I do not know of any other way, and don't think there is any, at least for tables that are CSV or excel formats, because of the fundamental limitation imposed by the way in which the data is stored (row by row) in them. There is a direct pointer (sort of) from one cell to the next in a row, but no such linkage exists for cells in a column across the different rows. Imagine it in this way - threads of equal length are laid on a table horizontally, one below the other (rows). You can traverse the length of the thread, but cannot jump from one point on one thread to its counterpart on the next!

Answer (score 1):

First, you will read 1st row after you can get all column values,below i have given how to read first row

```
public void readFirstRow(String filename)
{

    List<String> fieldsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

     try{

            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));

            Workbook workBook = null;

            workBook    = new HSSFWorkbook(myInput);

            Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

            Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);

            int length  = firstRow.getLastCellNum();

            Cell cell = null;

            for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )

                {
                     cell = firstRow.getCell(i);

                     fieldsArrayList.add(cell.toString());

                }

     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Read column Values code:

//You just pass the cityPostion and filename

```
public void readColumnValues(int cityPosition,String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        Workbook workBook = null;

        workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myInput);
        Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum() ; i++ )
        {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            if (i > 0) //skip first row
            {

                Cell cityCell   = row.getCell(cityPosition);


                String cityNames      = cityCell.toString();
            }

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Might be it will help to you...

Comment: Check for null rows and null cells unless you want NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: @parthi:
    public void readFirstRow(String filename)
 {try{  FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
           Workbook workBook = null;
           workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myInput);
           Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
           Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
           int length  = firstRow.getLastCellNum();
           Cell cell = null;
           for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )
           { cell = firstRow.getCell(i);
   if (cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(UserInput))
        {hmap.put(cell, fieldsArrayList);}}} }